# Get total cost for a customer call

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables = customer and their call history

Now I want to charge them based on call duration and that too for a specific month say Jan 2015.

Here is the criteria to calculate the cost for calls -

A) For incoming calls, the charge is 1 unit per second. `Example if the duration is 250 seconds then cost is 250`

B) For outgoing calls, `for the first 2mins, the cost is fixed at 500 units`. for subsequent seconds the cost is `2 units per second`.

Example if the outgoing duration is 5mins then cost is `500 units + 2*3*60 units = 860 units`

Below are the tables:

`customer table with columns id, name, phone`

`history table with columns id, incoming_phone, outgoing_phone, duration, dialed_on (YYYY-MM-DD)`

I have come up with below queries for my conditions:

For incoming call cost:

```
select c.name, c.phone, h.duration as cost
from customer c join history h on c.phone = h.incoming_phone
```

When I run the above query I did not get any syntax errors.

For outgoing call cost:

```
select c.name, c.phone, CASE
    WHEN h.duration > 120 THEN 500 + 2*(h.duration-120)
    ELSE 2*(h.duration-120)
END; as cost
from customer c join history h on c.phone = h.outgoing_phone
```

When I run the above query I got `syntax error like "ERROR 1109 (42S02) at line 1: Unknown table 'c' in field list"`

I want to join these two queries and get the total cost and display the fields as name, phone, cost

I still need to add a condition for a specific month to restrict data for Jan 2015, but got stuck with the approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is due to the extra semicolon `;` after `END`.

Sounds like your final query will be this:

```
SELECT c.name, 
       c.phone, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN h.direction = 'in' THEN h.duration END) as IncomingCost,
       SUM(CASE WHEN h.direction = 'out' AND h.duration > 120 THEN 500 + 2*(h.duration-120)
                WHEN h.direction = 'out' AND h.duration <= 120 THEN 500
       END) as OutgoingCost,
       SUM(CASE WHEN h.direction = 'in' THEN h.duration END +
       CASE WHEN h.direction = 'out' AND h.duration > 120 THEN 500 + 2*(h.duration-120)
            WHEN h.direction = 'out' AND h.duration <= 120 THEN 500
       END) as TotalCost
FROM customer c 
JOIN (SELECT 'out' as directon, duration, dialed_on, outgoing_phone as phone 
      FROM history 
      WHERE YEAR(dialed_on) = 1995
      AND MONTH(dialed_on) = 1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'in' as direction, duration, dialed_on, incoming_phone as phone
      FROM history
      WHERE YEAR(dialed_on) = 1995
      AND MONTH(dialed_on) = 1
     ) h ON c.phone = h.phone
GROUP BY c.name,
         c.phone
```

Comment: For incoming call cost, I have to join with `incoming_phone` for the outgoing cost I have to join with `outgoing_phone`

Comment: @learner Whoops, overlooked that.  Probably the easiest fix is to normalize that structure with a `union`, then add an extra condition to the sums for each call direction.

Comment: How to union both queries and calculate the total cost

Comment: @AaronDietz hey why do you have (duration - 120) * 2 this would produce negative cost no ? and isn't it should be just a  fixed cost of 500 if the duration is less than 2 minutes

Comment: @AaronDietz you can fix those now ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question in an evaluation with different table names and date. Here's how I sorted out the incoming vs outgoing records.

```
select c.name, c.phone_number, i.incoming_cost + o.outgoing_cost call_unit

from customer_detail c

left join 
(select c.phone_number, sum(duration) as incoming_cost 
from call_record r right join customer_detail c
on c.phone_number = r.incoming_number
where year(dialed_on)=2018
and month(dialed_on)=05
group by c.phone_number
) i on c.phone_number = i.phone_number

left JOIN
(select c.phone_number, sum(case when duration > 120 then 500+ 2*(duration-120)
    when duration <=120 then 500
    end) as outgoing_cost 
from call_record r right join customer_detail c
on c.phone_number = r.outgoing_number 
where year(dialed_on)=2018
and month(dialed_on)=05
group by c.phone_number
) o on c.phone_number = o.phone_number
```